# Android: cancelling alarm in service

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I am starting a series of alarms inside an activity to start a service after specific time. After the service is started I want to cancel that particular alarm and not any other alarm.

Below is the code for starting the alarm.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
Intent intent = new Intent(StatAlarmActivity.this, AndroidService.class);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getService(StatAlarmActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), i*24*60*60*1000, pIntent); //i varies, i is no of days after which the service will start
```

How can I cancel a particular alarm after the service is started? I tried below code inside the AndroidService but I can't access StartAlarmActivity.this and getSystemService here.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
Intent intent = new Intent(StatAlarmActivity.this, AndroidService.class);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getService(StatAlarmActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.cancel(pIntent);
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Try getActivity() instead of StatAlarmActivity.this

Comment: Why are you starting alarm as repeating if you want to stop it the first time it runs?

Comment: @weston What should I use then?

Comment: [`alarm.set(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent))

Answer (score 1):

Try **getActivity()** instead of **StatAlarmActivity.this** if you are cancelling the alarm manager in a different activity than you start.

The first argument is the context.

From [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent(android.content.Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent%28android.content.Context), java.lang.Class)

Syntax :

public Intent (Context packageContext, Class cls)

Parameters :
packageContext  A Context of the application package implementing this class.
cls The component class that is to be used for the intent.